# match and originalkey to resize Image in lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm working with lambda function to resize the upload image in my s3 bucket, I'm encountering few problems with the following code, Can anyone explain what is "**const match**"  and  "**originalKey**" I tried several combination . none helped me.

```
 'use strict';
 const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 const S3 = new AWS.S3({
 accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
 secretAccessKey: "yyyyyyyyyyy", 
region: "us-east-1", 
signatureVersion: 'v4',
});

const Sharp = require('sharp');
const BUCKET = "patientimg"; 
const URL = "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com";
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
const match = key.match(/(\d+)x(\d+)\/(.*)/);
const width =10;
const height =10;
const originalKey ="ImageName";

S3.getObject({Bucket: BUCKET, Key: originalKey}).promise()
.then(data => Sharp(data.Body)
 .resize(width, height)
  .toFormat('png')
    .toBuffer()
 )
 .then(buffer => S3.putObject({
   Body: buffer,
    Bucket: BUCKET,
     ContentType: "image/png",
       Key: key,
        }).promise()
    )
.then(() => callback(null, {
   statusCode: '301',
    headers: {'location': "${URL}/${key}"},
      body: "",
  })
)
 .catch(err => callback(err))
}
```

output:

error occured in match[1], match[2] and match[3]

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes the uploaded object key matches a specific pattern `/(\d+)x(\d+)\/(.*)/`, which means:

```
\d+ 1 or more digits - match[1]
x a literal x
\d+ 1 or more digits - match[2]
\/ a literal slash
.* zero or more of any character - match[3]
```

If your object key doesn't match this pattern, the code would break.

Comment: errorMessage":"The specified key does not exist ... Though after making height, width and original key explicit . as above code(modified)

Comment: const match = key.match(/(\d+)x(\d+)\/(.*)/); always returns null

Comment: copied code from  the following link https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-resizing/blob/master/lambda/index.js

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is struggling with this. Its not a * but its an x.

So the url for starting this should be like this

[http://**webpageendpointtobucket**/200x200/earth.jpg](http://__webpageendpointtobucket__/200x200/earth.jpg)